# Need to replace arrays with strings

Tags: php

I have this string: `CO2 + H2O + XO`

And I am going for this: `CO2 + H2O + NaO`.

I have researched this quite a bit and I am at a loss on what to do with a mixture of strings and arrays.

```
$reactant = 'CO2 + H2O + XO';

$products = str_split($reactant);

foreach ($products as $splitresult)
{
  $splitresult = str_replace('X', 'Na', $splitresult); 
}

echo $splitresult;
```

Comment: do you want to replace all the X's as 'Na' or only when they are next to 'O' ? I ask because as you are working with elements there are other(s) elements including an X as far as I remember, and if you are putting this as just an example and it's not the real scenario specify as much as possible so we can work out something accurate.

Comment: Ok, so when you say _X_ in string you mean `$someElement`. This is handled very easily with `str_replace($searchFor, $replaceWith, $subject)`

Comment: I am working on decomposition reactions. On this specific one,  i don't know the metals and i use place holders i.e X. It only covers upto AP level, so i don't expect anyone looking for X or Y elements. Str_split also seems to work better than explode.

Comment: @Edwinner can I ask why `str_split` works better than `explode` for you?

Comment: @Stanyer that was before i tried yours. explode does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

echo str_replace('X', 'Na', $reactant) ;

Answer (score 2):

If you're always going to be joining the elements up with a plus sign, you could explode the string as so:

```
$parts = explode(' + ', $reactant);
```

Then loop around the array

```
foreach($parts as &$part) {
    $part = str_replace('X', 'Na', $part);
}
```

Then to display the results, implode the array back together using the plus:

```
$reactant = implode(' + ', $parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about just this :

```
<?php
 $reactant = 'CO2 + H2O + XO';
 $reactant = str_replace('X', 'Na', $reactant);
?>
```

If you really want to split because your code is longer, you have to set via the key, because the `$splitresult` will be overwritten after each loop pass. It's a temporary variable. Here is the right way to do it :

```
<?php
 $reactant = 'CO2 + H2O + XO';
 $products = str_split($reactant);

 foreach($products as $i=>$splitresult)
 {
  $products[$i] = str_replace('X', 'Na', $splitresult) ;
 }
 $reactant = implode('',$products);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$reactant = 'CO2 + H2O + XO';
$products = explode($reactant, ' + ');

foreach($products as $key => $splitresult)
{
    $products[ $key ] = str_replace('X', 'Na', $splitresult);
}
print_r( $products );
```